# Move left sidebar at the bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm actually using bootstrap 3 to create a website, and I would like to move a left side bar at the bottom of the page when my page is in mobile view (320px width).
Is there any possiblity to achieve that only with css ?
I try the col-md-push-* but it's absolutly not working.

Here is the code :

http://jsfiddle.net/krL115nn/4/

```
<div> Block A (side bar)</div>
<div> Block B (tiles)</div>
<div> Block B ''</div>
<div> Block B ''</div>
<div> Block B ''</div>
```

I would like to move the Block A at the end of the page after all Block B tiles when the size of the page is 320px width.

Does anyone know a way to achieve that?

Comment: I'd encourage you to learn about [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order of your columns and use `pull-left` and `pull-right` to reposition them:

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/Eevw4np8GT#)

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content" class="offerList">
        <div class="row clearfix">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 column pull-right">
                <!-- Block B -->
                ...

            </div>

            <div id="contactBlock" class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 column pull-left">
                <!-- Block A -->
                ...

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At larger screen sizes this will float Block A to the left and Block B to the right effectively swapping their positions within the parent element. At small screen sizes when your columns are 100% width these floats become meaningless (an element can't be 'floated' above another element) and the order of the elements in the DOM takes over.

Comment: Perfect !! It's works properly :)
Do not understand why in fact, but it works !